# ffmpeg 1080p50 50fps unsupported on some samsung models, resulting in Error

Tags: ffmpeg, nvenc

So I use FFMPEG for live transcoding using nvenc gpu acceleration. I recently did some minor improvements by upping the framerate to 1080p50 instead of 1080p25.

I noticed that this caused "error" messages on some samsung models. I was wondering if it is due to my code, can we up the compatibility or are the tv's just unable to playback 1080p50 which I think is really strange.

This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -vcodec h264_cuvid -vcodec h264_cuvid -i 'rtmp://127.0.0.1:8001/input/bla' -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -map 0:v -map 0:a -vf yadif_cuda=1 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v h264_nvenc -preset llhq -vprofile high -level 4.2 -rc:v vbr -qmin:v 18 -qmax:v 42 -b:v 6M -maxrate 6M -bufsize 12M -threads 0 -r 50 -g 200 -f flv 'rtmp://127.0.0.1:8001/input/test'
```

Like 80% of the models, samsung/lg/sony are able to play it but some small amount of samsung tv's give stream error. I have a feeling it is just the high framerate where the tv/app is unable to play it back resulting in "streaming error". Because on even older lg models the stream plays back just perfectly. It does not seem to be a format or something...

Answer (score 0):

1080p25 Requires the decoder to support level 4.1. 1080p50 requires 4.2. Check the manufacturers  specifications of each  devices to the max level it supports.

Comment: But it works fine when i output 1080p25 and still keep level 4.2 in the command. Or is that level ignored since the output is 1080p25?

Comment: I found this regarding 2014 samsung models. So bad of samsung to not include 50fps decoding on 2014 and lower tv's. My 2011 LG can even decode 1080p50
https://www.samsung.com/in/support/tv-audio-video/what-are-the-supported-video-codecs-available-in-samsung-h-series-tv/

Comment: TVs are a very low margin item. If they can save 5 cents by including a previous generation video decoder chip, they will.

Comment: Yea but always on samsung tv's while LG's are cheaper and have less margin so strange.